# Connect to UICC with NFC antenna and CCID

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, sim-card, smartcard-reader

I've got a contactless smard card reader and a UICC inside an NFC enabled devive (Android phone).  I'd like to connect to the UICC from a PC, using the phone's NFC antenna and the contactless reader. Are there any API which can grant me access to the UICC this way? I know there is an API called openmobile which let me to connect to the UICC from a mobile application.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the UICC "NFC-enabled"? I.e. does it support single wire protocol (SWP)? What Android device are you using?

Comment: As far as I know it supports SWP (Oberthur SIM, GP22). I'm using a Galaxy S III and DUALi's Dragon contactless card interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to distinguish 2 cases:

1. One external contactless reader connected to the PC (via USB I guess)
2. No reader at all, just the device with this UICC in it.

I'm currently working with both cases and I've succesfully written and read data to/from an UICC with an external reader (ACR122U). But the special thing is that this card is formatted by my MNO provider so I can do that easily: Mifare Classic alike. This UICC "has" a emulated Mifare 1K classic in it so I just have to connect to the device as a 14443-3 tag and work with it as a common Mifare card. I've been working with a Vodafone NFC enabled SIM and this is how they sell their new NFC SIMs after you have enabled the Vodafone Wallet. I'm still researching on how to format the card if its not formatted this way.

This has some catches, for instance, if the card is not formatted like this, as I said, I still have no idea how to do format it like a Mifare and work with it like that. As soon as I lnow I will edit this answer :) Notice that no OpenMobileAPI has been used here, since you are connecting to the UICC like a common tag. Nasty things come when you are solely working in the phone...

In case this is your case, you have to check the ATR of the card to see if you are working with 14443-4 or 14443-3 tags (Google can help you to get the format of both tags and distinguish them). In case it is a -4, you have to disable ATS so you don't jump to -4 and stay in Mifare's, -3 level. From here, you have just a Mifare card and its easy to go from here using 7816-4 apdus :)

For this second case; I'm still not able to write data or read it from the UICC and I'm waiting for my UICC provider to give some How-To

In case I'm missing something or your case its like this, please let me know!